# Admin Levels/User Role implementation in PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to implement a Admin Level/User role into my website, I am fairly new to PHP so still trying to figure a few things out.

I have this SQL query:

```
$sqlUserLevel = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM po_users");
$sqlUserLevel->execute();
$loggedInUserRole = $sqlUserLevel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and this PHP if statement:

```
if($loggedInUserRole['userRole'] == "Admin"){
    include 'file.php';
  }else{
  //dont show.
}
```

But the content is still showing to everyone not just "Admin" users can someone point me in the right direction...

Comment: please note that youre fetching all the rows from your users table

Comment: AS the above comments suggests, you need a where clause `$sqlUserLevel = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM po_users WHERE user_id = $currentUserID");`

Comment: Thanks both, this has helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query may be wrong , My opinion is please try to select the user role from op_user rather than * . What happens here you first record always looking and the if condition never gonna true. so that's why you getting this issue . Please have a try. This may help you.

Please change this as what you want.

```
 $sqlUserLevel = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT userRole FROM po_users where uid='".$myUid."'");
    $sqlUserLevel->execute();
    $loggedInUserRole = $sqlUserLevel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    if($loggedInUserRole['userRole'] == "Admin"){
        include 'file.php';
      }else{
      //dont show.
    }
```

Please have a try this may help you.

Comment: But please do not use that query. There should never be a variable directly in a query (good rule of thumb). Granted, if the variable is pulled directly from other hardcoded values, or taken directly from another query, it might be okay, but as a general rule, always use prepared queries.